# The entity type 'AlarmReciever' requires a primary key to be defined

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I have two models that both have a many-to-one relation and a many-to-many relation.
A user can create many alarms but an alarm can only have one creator.
A user can recieve many alarms and alarms have many recievers.

```
public class AppUser
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public virtual IEnumerable<Alarm> CreatedAlarms { get; set; }
    [InverseProperty("AlarmRecievers")]
    public virtual IEnumerable<Alarm> RecievedAlarms { get; set; }

    public AppUser()
    {
        CreatedAlarms = new HashSet<Alarm>();
        RecievedAlarms = new HashSet<Alarm>();
    }
}
```

and

```
public class Alarm
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("AppUser")]
    public Guid? AppUserId { get; set; }
    public AppUser AppUser { get; set; }
   
    [InverseProperty("RecievedAlarms")]
    public virtual IEnumerable<AppUser> AlarmRecievers { get; set; }
    public Alarm()
    {
        AlarmRecievers = new HashSet<AppUser>();
    }  
}
```

but when I try to add a migrations, I get the title as an error. I did expect there to be a created a AlarmReciever table but considering I don't have the model in my code I don't know how to create the key.

Earlier I had

```
modelBuilder.Entity<AlarmReciever>()
           .HasKey(c => new { c.AppUserId, c.AlarmId });
```

but I'm trying to get rid of the join table in my code so I'd like to do it the way I'm trying to

Comment: Since you're getting this error it means you're using EF Core which doesn't support many to many relationships by default so a join table is mandatory for this to work.

Comment: Alright, thank you. I missed that